# Explorer properties slow for large Delphi executable

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

With our 80MB Delphi app on a network share we are finding that a right mouse click Properties in explorer is very slow (around 30 seconds) Similar sized programs on the same drive don't have the problem.

I'm wondering if the Delphi linker organizes the exe in a way that means explorer needs to read the whole file to find the properties information and if there is a way to change this? I can't see anything obvious in the project settings.

**EDIT**

We have these options in the project file:

```
{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}
{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
```

but I think these will only affect the program when it is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay was caused by the PW option flags I mentioned in the question. Taking them out and all is well.

Now I need to find out why they were put there.

Comment: PW? Do you mean PE?

Comment: `IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP` is to mitigate (some of the) issues that result from running executables from network shares which is a, wide spread, but very bad practice.